# SQL Server 2008R2 OBJECT_ID

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Im new to SQL SERVER , I was going through some of the examples in MSDN . I understood what OBJECT_ID does. but i was confused the way it was in the example .

USE tempdb;

GO

IF OBJECT_ID (N'#Bicycles',N'U') IS NOT NULL

DROP TABLE #Bicycles;

Why are we writing N and # ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the `#` symbol prefixes a temporary table name and `N` denotes type `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR` or `NTEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

"N" is used to indicate that the string is unicode (NVARCHAR as opposed to VARCHAR).  In this case, you could equally not specify the N and it would still work.

The "#" indicates the table is a temporary table.